Parsing the definition of the power set axiom: why does it include _all_ subsets?
I am reading Wikipedia's definition:
$\forall x \, \exists y \, \forall z \, [z \in y \iff \forall w \, (w \in z \Rightarrow w \in x)]$
I understand why any element of the power set $y$ is a subset of the set $x$, but I don't fully see why the power set will include all subsets of $x$.
I suspect this is a lack of conceptual understanding of the quantifiers on my side. The best interpretation I have so far is:

$\forall z \, [z \in y$ is covering all elements of the power set
$\forall w \, (w \in z$ is covering all elements belonging to $z$, a subset of $x$

but I'm not sure why it will also cover all elements of the given set $x$



(The above is a rough conceptual sketch. I get that all universal quantifiers act over the entire domain of discourse and that there is no "specific" quantifier for each set but wanted to show my partial understanding as best as possible.)

What's the power set of $x$?

@SassatelliGiulio You mean what's the definition of a power set? Or are you asking about some ambiguity in my question?

I guess I'd like to read the definition.

It's in the link of the post: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set#Formal_statement. Roughly speaking, it means a set that contains all the possible subsets of another set.

Ok, fine by me.

It's the inside stuff that is important "$\forall w(w\in z \iff w\in x)$" means nothing more or less than $z\subseteq x$.  So $[z\in y \iff \forall w(w\in z\iff w\in x)]$ means $z\in y \iff z\subset x$ and .... that really should answer your question, shouldn't it? $y$ consist of all subsets of $x$ and only subsets of $x$.

Note you wrote $\iff$ instead of $\Rightarrow$ in the inner parenthesis. I'm assuming you did it on purpose to help readability and both are equivalent. This actually clarifies it for me, thanks.

@lucas No, that $\iff$ is incorrect, a typo I presume. It should be $\Rightarrow.$ (With the $\iff$ that RHS would be equivalent (given axiom of extensionality) to $z=x$, not to $z\subseteq x$.)

@fleablood see above comment.

Definitely a typo!  I meant to write exactly as was written.  They are most certainly not equivalent.  If the were equivalent that would men $z$ and $x$ are the exact same set.  I meant that $z$ is a subset of $x$.  IF $w\in z$ then $w\in x$.  That it clarifies actually disturbs me.

@spaceisdarkgreen is absolutely correct and it is a typo and a fatal one.  I am grateful they gave me enough credit to recognize I couldn't possibly mean $\iff$

$$
\forall w (w\in z \implies w \in x)
$$
Means that $z$ is a subset of $x$. That is, if any element $w$ is in $z$ then it is also in $x$. So we rewrite/translate/abbreviate this as $z\subset x$. So we can rewrite the axiom:
$$
\forall x \exists y \forall z(z\in y \iff z\subset x)
$$
Recall that $\iff$ is "if and only if". That is $A\iff B$ is equivalent to $(A\implies B )\land (B\implies A)$. In this case it is the only if direction that tells us all subsets of $x$ are in the posited set $y$ (which will become the power set $\mathcal{P}(x)$). Namely the axiom above implies
$$
z\subset x \implies z \in y.
$$
Any subset $z$ of $x$ is contained in the set $y$.

If instead the axiom read
$$
\forall x \exists y \forall z(z\in y \implies z\subset x)
$$
(Note $\implies$ instead of $\iff$).Then that would tell there is a set that only contains subsets of $x$. That is, there exists a set $y$ which is a subset of the powerset of $x$. But the actual axiom has $\iff$ which means in addition to $z\in y \implies z \subset x$ we also have $z\subset x \implies z \in y$. So I really think the answers boils down to a misconception or forgetting about exactly how $\iff$ works.

Answering a question in the comments:
If we have proven, from a given theory (e.g. a given set of axioms and deduction rules), a statement of the form
$$
\forall x \exists! y \phi_f(x, y)
$$
then* we can conservatively extend the theory by adding a function symbol $f(x)$ and the axiom
$$
\forall x \phi_f(x, f(x))
$$
We can call this axiom the definitional axiom for $f$ and we can call $\phi_f$ the definitional predicate for $f$.
For the case of the powerset, from the axiom of the powerset we immediately have
$$
\forall x \exists y \forall z(z\in y \iff z\subset x)
$$
With a little work using the axiom of extensionality we can extend this to
$$
\forall x \exists! y \forall z (z\in y \iff z\subset x)
$$
So if we let $\phi_{\mathcal{P}(x)}(x, y) \equiv \forall z (z\in y \iff z \subset x)$ we see we can make a conservative extension to our theory by defining the functional symbol $\mathcal{P}(x)$ and adding the definitional axiom
$$
\forall x \phi_{\mathcal{P}(x)}(x, \mathcal{P}(x))
$$
which we can expand as
$$
\forall x \forall z(z\in \mathcal{P}(x) \iff z\subset x)
$$
So to really answer the question in the comments: The definitional predicate for $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is $\forall z (z\in y \iff z \subset x)$. You really need the $\iff$ here. $z\subset x \implies z \in y$ would not suffice. If we only had $\implies$ like this then we would admit non subsets of $x$ in the powerset of $x$ and that is not allowed. That is we can't have $\mathcal{P}(\{1, 2\}) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{3\}\}$, though this set satisfies $\forall z(z\subset x \implies z \in y)$. So we really need the $\iff$. Furthermore, if we only had $\implies$ then we wouldn't be able to prove that $y$ is unique. There are an infinite number of sets that contain all the subsets of $x$, but there is only one set that contains exactly the subsets of $x$.
*I'm playing a bit fast and loose here, I should really use variable/term substitution notation here

Thanks for the detailed explanation. If I can do a follow-up: is $ z\subset x \implies z \in y$ (like you wrote in "Namely the axiom above implies..." and I also see in another Wiki definition I didn't cite before) enough to define the power set here or do we need also $ z\subset x \iff z \in y$?

I think the Wikipedia definition of the power set then applies a further "filter" by taking the subset of that $y$ that are only subsets of $x$, which I guess it would imply the $\iff$: $P(x)  = {z \in y : z \subseteq x}$.

I gave some extensive prose on how we formally extend a theory in formal logic by adding a new function symbol. The upshot is that the definitional predicate for $\mathcal{P}(x)$ requires $z\subset x \iff z\in y$. It would not suffice to have $z\subset x \implies z\in y$. The latter admits the possibility of non-subsets of $x$ being in the set $y$, which is not allowed for $\mathcal{P}(x)$. In short $\mathcal{P}(x)$ satisfies $\forall x \forall z (z\in \mathcal{P}(x) \iff z\subset x)$.

That appendix was very informative in many respects, thanks!!

Suppose there is a $z\subset x$ with $z\not\in y$. By the axiom of power set, this is equivalent of saying there is a $w\in z$, such that $w\not\in x$. This is a contradiction.
More detailed:
Suppose $\exists z\subset x:z\not\in y$. (Suppose there is a $z\subset x$ with $z\not\in y$.) By the axiom of power set, this is equivalent of saying $\neg(\forall w(w\in z\Rightarrow w\in x))$ is true. Note, that
$$\neg(\forall w(w\in z\Rightarrow w\in x)) = \exists w \neg(w\in z\Rightarrow w\in x) = \exists w (w\in z)\wedge (w\not \in x)$$
This means, there is an element $w$ in the subset $z$, which is not element of $x$. This cannot be true, so your assumption $\exists z\subset x:z\not\in y$ is false and therefore
$$\neg(\exists z\subset x:z\not\in y)=\forall z\subset x:z\in y$$
is true, i.e. every subset of $x$ is element of the power set.
Another way:
Just notice, that
$$z\subset x = \forall w(w\in z\Rightarrow w\in x)$$
and rewrite the axiom of power set as
$$\forall x\ \exists y \ \forall z\  (z\in y \Leftrightarrow z\subset x)$$
This clearly means, that $y$ has to be the set which contains every subset of $x$.

I am sure what your are saying is correct but I don't find helpful in my situation invoking the very same axiom I'm trying to understand.

Thanks for the additional details. I agree with your logic and the spirit of the axiom; I just don't understand its definition. So I also don't understand the step "By the axiom of power set, this is equivalent of saying: ..." because I don't understand how the axiom is expressing "all the subsets" in formal logic.

$z\subset x \Leftrightarrow \forall w (w\in z \Rightarrow w\in x)$

Powerset Axiom: ∀∃∀[∈⟺∀(∈⇒∈)]
In English
For any set x, there exists a set y ( we call the Powerset of x), such that for all sets z, z is an element of y if and only if every element of z is an element of x.
Here is an example.
Let x = {1}
By the powerset Axiom find y s.t.
∀(∈ ⟺ ∀(∈⇒∈))
Let's look at the subsets of x.
$z_1$ = ∅
$z_2$ = {1}
Now, why are $z_1$,$z_2$ elements of y?
To show an element is in y, we need to satisfy the following condition:
∀(∈⇒∈)
Is $z_1$∈y?
Let's check, ∀(∈$z_1$⇒∈)- is true! vacuously as the empty set contains no elements.
Is $z_2$∈y?
Let's check, ∀(∈$z_2$⇒∈)
∀(∈{1}⇒∈)
As {1} only has a single element, we just need to check if w = 1 is an element of x.
Indeed, 1 is an element of x. Thus $z_2$∈y.
